# how to subtract one list from another including duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 2 lists

On is a big list with some elements having duplicates
`super_set_list = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

The other is a subset of the big list, also with duplicates
`sub_set_list = [1,2,3,3,4,4,6,7,9]`

I want the difference, like this
`diff = [1,4,5,8]`

Not sure how I would go about this

Comment: You could use a Counter from collections

Comment: @Learningisamess yes for sure, and then you can difference two counters.  So one option... `functools.reduce(list.__add__, [[val]*n for val, n in (Counter(super_set_list) - Counter(sub_set_list)).items()])`

Comment: If order doesn't matter use sets and find the difference.

Comment: Alternative way to write the above: `[val for val, n in (Counter(super_set_list) - Counter(sub_set_list)).items() for _ in range(n)]`

Comment: Suppose that your `sub_set_list` did not contain any `1` elements at all: how many times would you want the number `1` to appear in `diff`: just once, or twice?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Counter`

```
super_set_list = [1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sub_set_list = [1,2,3,3,4,4,6,7,9]

from collections import Counter
super_counter = Counter(super_set_list)
```

super_counter = Counter({1: 3, 4: 3, 3: 2, 2: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1})

For every element in `sub_set_list`, reduce the count in in `super_counter`

```
for item in sub_set_list:
    super_counter[item]-=1
```

Now super_counter = Counter({1: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 8: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 9: 0})

Finally, just pick elements that have some count left (but add it that many number of times).

```
diff=[]
for k,v in super_counter.items():
    for _ in range(v):
        diff.append(k)
print(diff)
# [1, 1, 4, 5, 8]
```

Comment: You don't need to check `item in super_counter` because nonexistent items have a count of `0`. You don't need to check `super_counter[item] >= 1` because you check `v > 0` later when building the list anyway

Comment: The example in the question is a poor one because the difference in item counts between the two lists is always either 0 or 1, but the description as "difference" suggests to me that in principle items could be required to appear multiple times in `diff` if the difference between counts is greater than 1 - which your code would not do.

Comment: @alani Made an edit to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through sub-set list and remove item in super-set list one by one as follows:

```
super_set_list = [1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8,9]
sub_set_list = [1,2,3,3,4,4,6,7,9]

for item in sub_set_list:
    if item in super_set_list:
        super_set_list.remove(item)
print(super_set_list)
```